# Test union return in typescript

Tags: typescript

I can't get simple unions working with typescript

considering the following code

```
function test(v: boolean) {
    if (v === true) {
        return { success: 'yolo' }
    }
    return { error: { code: 32, message: 'nop' } }
}

const val = test(true)

if (val.error) {
    alert(val.error.message)
}
```

I get the following error `Property 'error' does not exist on type '{ error: { code: number; message: string; } } | { success: boolean; }'`

Is there is any way to test which value in union is returned ?

Thanks !

Comment: You can try to use instaceof or just go for checking if the property exists and handle it as any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom type guard, like this - although you can make it as simple or complex as you like. I have made sure this example works as a stand alone one:

```
interface SuccessExample {
    success: string;
}

interface ErrorExample {
    error: { code: number; message: string }
}

function test(v: boolean) : SuccessExample | ErrorExample {
    if (v === true) {
        return { success: 'yolo' }
    }
    return { error: { code: 32, message: 'nop' } }
}

// Custom Type Guard - you can be as simple or complex as you like
function isError(arg: any): arg is ErrorExample {
    return arg.error !== undefined
        && arg.error.code !== undefined
        && arg.error.success !== undefined;
}

const val = test(true)

if (isError(val)) {
    alert(val.error.message)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I though this was a bit verbose compared to Flowtype which can dynamically infer union types.
But maybe returning different shape of value is simply not the Typescript way to do :)